# Stack implementation, array-based

Tags: java, stack

My understanding is that Stack possesses LIFO property. And, based upon that I have written the following program:

```
// This is a sample program to demonstrate push and pop
// functionality in Stack in Java.

package collections;

public class Stack_Array {

    private static final int capacity = 3;
    int[] arr = new int[capacity];
    int top = -1;

    public void push(int pushedElement) {
        if(top >= capacity) {
            System.out.println("StackOverflow !!");
        } else {
            top++;
            arr[top] = pushedElement;
        }
    }

    public void pop() {
        if(top>=0) {
            top--;          
        } else {
            System.out.println("Stack underflow !!");
        }
    }

    public void printStack() {
        System.out.println("Elements in Stack are: ");
        for(int i = top; i >=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack_Array s1 = new Stack_Array();
        s1.push(23);
        s1.push(21);
        s1.push(14);

        s1.pop();
        s1.printStack();
    }

}
```

Please let me know if it is the correct approach. 
Or, is there a better way to implement the same

Answer (score 4):

I like the consistency of your braces and indentation - well done!

The name `Stack_Array` should be `StackArray`, since as *member* names are `camelCase`, *type* names ought to be `PascalCase`, not `Upper_Snake_Case`.

---

You'll want to implement a **constructor** so that the `capacity` of the object can be parameterized, and then the calling code can look like this:

```
StackArray foo = new StackArray(42);
foo.push(bar);
```

The underlying `capacity` static field would need to be changed a bit though; you'll want it to be an *instance* field, so that each *object* can have its own independent value. I'd keep it `final` though, because it's not a value you want to be able to modify during the lifetime of an instance - beyond the *constructor*, nothing should be allowed to modify that value.

---

You'll want to throw an appropriate **exception** in *exceptional* situations:

> ```
> if(top >= capacity) {
>     System.out.println("StackOverflow !!");
> ```

A `Stack` is a *data structure*; other code will rely on its correct behavior, and *expect* a number of errors to occur in certain specific situations - for example when the caller attempts to `push` an element into an instance that already contains as many items as it can hold.

That said, I'd prefer a `Stack` implementation that simply increases its capacity as items are pushed. In any case, printing "StackOverflow !!" isn't appropriate. Making the method return a `bool` that the calling code can evaluate to determine whether the push/pull succeeded or not, would be a better alternative if you *really* want a fixed capacity.

---

Printing to the console isn't the job of a data structure, `printStack` should be replaced by a method that *returns* a new data structure that contains a *copy* of the internal array. Such a `toArray` method would leave it up to the calling code to decide whether they want to print the items to the console, or dump them into a log file, or whatever.

---

Your implementation is pretty bare-bones, you'll want to look at the [`java.util.Stack<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) members and possibly dig into generics. The C# [`System.Collections.Generics.Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) class could also be an inspiration.

The `pop` method would be expected to *return* the popped item. A `peek` method is missing, to "peek" at the next item without popping it out of the stack.

---

**Other observations**

Between `push` and `pop`, the two have an `if` conditional, but one is no-op in the positive branch, while the other is no-op in the negative branch (/`else` block). It would be better to decide whether you test for the error condition *[to throw an error and fail early]* or if you test for the success condition *[and throw an error in the `else` block]* - it's usually better to *fail early* and reduce the indentation level:

```
public void foo() {
    if ({error condition}) {
        throw new SomeException();
    }
    doSomething();
}
```

Watch the spacing on either side of comparison operators:

> ```
> for(int i = top; i >=0; i--) {
> ```

Give it the same whitespace as for the `=` assignment operator:

```
for(int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
```